# If 0.2=(x-4.8) / x, what is x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In 1966, the operative mortality rate in open heart surgery at a certain hospital was 8,1 per 100 cases. By 1974, the operative mortality rate had declined to 4,8 per 100 cases. If the rate declined by 20 percent from 1973 to 1974, by approximately what percent did it decline from 1966 to 1973?

The answer is this: 20% change: $0.2=(x-4.8)/x \implies x=6.$

Now solve for the change from 1966 to 1973: $x=(6-8.1)/8.1\implies x=0.25$ or 25%.

Question is how you get $x$? with the following: 
$0.2=(x-4.8)/x$

Can someone break it down for me?

Comment: Multiply both sides by non-zero $x$ and rearrange

Comment: Solving for $x$ is not the hard part here. The hard part is to understand the logic behind forming the equation. It is not trivial!

Comment: Also note that the percentage change from 1966 to 1973 is $\frac{(8.1-6)\times 100}{8.1}\approx. 25.93 \%$, so closer to $26\%$ than $25\%$.

Answer (score 0):

$0.2=(x-4.8)/x  \iff 0.2x=x-4.8 \iff -0.8x=-4.8 \iff x=6.$

Answer (score 0):

To solve for $ x $ in the equation $$ 0.2 = \frac{x - 4.8}{x} $$

Multiply $ x $ to both sides to eliminate the denominator on the right hand side:

$$0.2\cdot x = \frac{x - 4.8}{x} \cdot x \Rightarrow 0.2x = x - 4.8 $$

Then, since the $ 0.2x $ on the left side and the $ x $ on the right side are "like" terms, subtract an $ x $ to both sides:

$$0.2x - x = x - 4.8 - x \Rightarrow -0.8x = -4.8 $$

Finally, divide the coefficient of $x$, $ -0.8 $ to each side:
$$\frac{-0.8x}{-0.8} = \frac{-4.8}{-0.8} \Rightarrow x = 6 $$ as expected.